# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't detect external monitor after waking up from suspend

Tags: 16.04, monitor

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 lts on my Razer black stealth. When I suspend the session and log back in, external monitor is not detected unless I reboot. Anyone had this problem before?

EDIT 1: 
Output from xrandr -q:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4160 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 155mm
   2560x1440     59.95 +  39.97  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00* 
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 connected 2560x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
   2560x1080     60.00*+
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output from w -oush:

```
adi      tty7     :0               12:17m /sbin/upstart --user
```

A monitor is connected to HDMI and I am typing this on the monitor. Don't know why xrandr shows it as disconnected.

Comment: Have you tried Alt + F3? This used to happed to me on a Generic monitor and Xubuntu 14.04 where it won't connect after standby. When selecting the output it detected it!
Give it a try and tell me what happens with you.

Comment: What does Alt + F3 do? Didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

List the displays:

```
xrandr --query (or w -oush)
```

1. Disable the dpms function of the display (:0) you want.

```
 xset -display :0 -dpms
```

2. If this does not work try this:

```
 setterm -powerdown 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but neither of these worked. I updated the question with xrandr output. Please take a look.