# Ubuntu 16.04 External monitor slow to turn on after suspend

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, suspend

I have a desktop with 3 monitors running Ubuntu 16.04 with graphics card: Gallium 0.4 on AMD PITCAIRN (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-72-generic, LLVM 3.8.0).

One monitor is a Chimei CMV221D connected via a DVI cable. After I resume from a suspend it takes around 5-10 minutes to come back on. The other 2 monitors work properly.

If I run the "Screen Display" program and slightly move one of the monitor's positions, and hit "Apply" then the Chimei monitor will wake up sometimes (not always).

The issue doesn't happen if the computer just sleeps from inactivity or if I lock the screen. It also seems to require a *long* suspend to reproduce it.

All 3 monitors are at an anti-clockwise rotation with the Chimei on the right. The Chimei monitor is at 1680x1050 (16:10) resolution.

I've seen [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849112/ubuntu-16-04-lts-wont-detect-external-monitor-after-waking-up-from-suspend) but it's not clear how to use `xset` for my particular monitor.

I ran `xrand --query` when the monitor was working and not working and the output is the same.

This is my xrandr output for just the Chimei monitor:

```
$ xrandr --query
...
DVI-0 connected 1050x1680+2340+370 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 511mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
...
```

This is the complete xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3390 x 2560, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1440x2560+900+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected 1050x1680+2340+370 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 511mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-1 connected 900x1600+0+453 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900      60.00*+
   1440x900      74.98    59.90  
   1280x800      74.93    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Thanks in advance!